# Evaluate URL to set values in webform

Tags: webforms, uri

I am sending a link for a survey (webform 3.x) to users.  Based on a variety of information, they receive a link in the format http://www.domain.com/group/userid.  I'm able to retrieve the /group easily and process this into a hidden field on my webform.  However, the page "/group/userid" does not exist.  I need to find a way to rewrite the URL to go to /group?i=userid.  I'm currently using clean URLs, but am open to changing.  When I attempted the rewrite via htaccess, I lost the theme of my site (likely a path issue).

Is there a module for this sort of thing?  Any suggestions?

KMT

Comment: Is the survey for anonymous or authenticated users?

Comment: anonymous (the userid is a random code sent that matches them back to their email addresses -- which they gave us).